# maintain radio button checked if there are validation errors

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

I have a view where there are some radio buttons, each one correspond to a post that exist in database. And below there is also a radio button to create a new post "create new post". When the page is acessed the "create new post" radio button is checked and so the other form fields below are empty

**Issue:** When a user select some radio button that corresponds to a existing post, the form fields are populated with the post stored info in the database using jQuery below. If the user change some info of the form, for example the date field, and introduce a date with a incorrect format and submit the form, it appears an error, but the "create post" radio button becomes checked, and so instead of the user continue in the context of edit the selected post he changes for a context to create a new post because the radio button "create new post" becomes checked.

Do you know how to fix that?

Form with each post radio button and "create new post" radio button and the other form fields:

```
<p>{{$anyPost}}-aaaaa</p>
<form id="editposts" method="post" 
      action="{{route('posts.update', ['post_id' => $post->id])}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {{csrf_field()}}
  <div>
    @foreach($posts as $post)
    <div class="form-check">
      <input {{ (old('radiobutton') && old('radiobutton') == $post->id) ? 'checked' : '' }} class="form-check-input radio" type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="{{ $post->id }}" id="{{$post->id}}">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        {{$post->title}}
      </label>
    </div>
    @endforeach
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input checked checked {{ (old('radiobutton') && old('radiobutton') == 'create_post') ? 'checked' : '' }} class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radiobutton" id="create_post"
           value="create_post">
    <label class="form-check-label">
      Create post
    </label>
  </div>

  <!-- form fields, here is the name but are more like description, etc -->


      <div class="form-group">
         <label>Post title</label>
         <input  type="text" required class="form-control" value="{{ old('title') }}" name="title" id="tile">
      </div>
      <input type="submit" id="poststore" value="Create"/>
      <input type="submit" id="postupdate" value="Update"/>

</form>
```

JS to populate the form fields based on selected post and to change form action based on radio button selected:

```
var posts = {!!  $post !!}
$("#postupdate").hide();
$("input[name='radiobutton']").click(function() {
  let id = $(this).attr("id");
  if (id == "create_post") {
    $("#postupdate").hide();
    $("#poststore").show();
    $("#editposts").attr('action', '{{route('posts.store', ['post_id' => $post->id])}}');
    $("input[name='title']").val("");
    ...
  } else {
    $("#postupdate").show();
    $("#poststore").hide();
    $("#editposts").attr('action', '{{route('posts.update', ['post_id' => $post->id])}}');
    let data = posts.find(e => e.id == id) || {
      title: "",
      ...

    };
      $("input[name='title']").val(data.title);
      ...
    }
    });
```

I have this "`->with('anyPost', $isAnyPostButtonChecked);`" in the controller to debug and "`<p>{{$anyPost}}-aaaaa</p>`" above the form but it appears always false before and also after submit the form.

```
public function edit($id)
{
    ...
    $isAnyPostButtonChecked = false;
    $isAnyPostButtonChecked = $isAnyPostButtonChecked && (old('radiobutton') && old('radiobutton') == $post->id);
    return view('posts.edit')
        ->with('posts', $post)
        ->with('anyPost', $isAnyPostButtonChecked);
}
```

The "{{var_dump(old('radiobutton')}}" shows:

NULL

Comment: please use a snippet to visually recreate the problem, it will be a lot more likely for you to get help that way

Comment: Thanks, but the issue includes php code, because the user is updating a post and submit the form, if there are validation error the radio button that becomes checked is the "create post" radio button, so the issue, it includes php code not only jquery and html.

Comment: `checked checked ` duplicated

Comment: Thanks, but like that, removing the two "checked", when there are validation errors after form is submited no checkbox is checked but it should be checked the radio button that corresponds to the post being edited. With only one "checked" I get the same issue of the question.

Comment: Which radio button is not checked? An input should have only one checked attribute, this one `{{ (old('radiobutton') && old('radiobutton') == 'create_post') ? 'checked' : '' }}`. I think your laravel validation is not passing required values.

Comment: what is $event->id

Comment: Thanks, I update the question.

Comment: Maybe dont works, because when the page is acessed at first the radio button "create new post" is checked by default. Then if a user wants to update a post, the user selects the radio button that corresponds to that post, the form fields appear and then the user can edit the form fields and click update, if there is some validation error I want to maintain the radio button of the post being edited checked. But dont works and should be because the "create new post" as "checked" by default.

Comment: Maybe a solution is to have no radio button checked at first when page is accessed. But that way, the form fields should be also hidden at first. Then if a user wants to update a post, the user selects the radio button that corresponds to that post, the form fields appear and then the user can edit the form fields and click update, if there is some validation error I want to maintain the radio button of the post being edited checked. But with this method is also not working because when are validation errors the form fields are hidden so the user can´t correct the errors.

Comment: @AdamK According to my knowledge your requirement as per question is feasible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

Change the `create_post` check box as follows..

```
<input {{ (empty(old('radiobutton')) || old('radiobutton') == 'create_post') ? 'checked' : '' }} class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radiobutton" id="create_post"
           value="create_post">
```

The `checked checked` static property is removed and only the conditional property is used [There is also a change]. If the form populate freshly or doesn't have a `old('radiobutton')` value or the `old('radiobutton')` value is `create_post` then the `create_post` check box is checked.

Also update your debug code..

```
public function edit($id, Request $request)
{
    ...
    $isAnyPostButtonChecked = false;
    $isAnyPostButtonChecked = $isAnyPostButtonChecked || !empty($request->get('radiobutton'));
    return view('posts.edit')
        ->with('posts', $post)
        ->with('anyPost', $isAnyPostButtonChecked);
}
```

Hope it helps.. Let me know if there is any issues..

Comment: Thanks, the post updating seems that it works. When the post is updated and there is validation errors the radio button maitains checked. But when I click in create new post, insert some values and then click in "update" it appears "Creating default object from empty value".

Comment: Update or store method? It seems that when the "create new post" radio button is clicked instead of the request go to the store method it goes to the update method.

Comment: public function update(Request $request, $id){

        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|string',
           ...
        ]);

        $postUpdate = Post::find($request->radiobutton);

        $postUpdate->name = $request->name;
       ...
        $postUpdate->save();

        Session::flash('success','success');

        return redirect()->back();
    }

Comment: @AdamK it seems that your form is pointed to update route. `action="{{route('posts.update', ['post_id' => $post->id])}}"`. then how it will call the create method?

Comment: submit to the `posts.create` url when creating new post. Use Js or use another form tag with new post url.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168671/discussion-between-ab-ab-and-adamk).

Answer (score 1):

You have two times `checked` on the radio button, remove it and then it will not be checked if the condition its not true.

So, change this:

```
<input checked checked {{ (old('radiobutton') && old('radiobutton') == 'create_post') ? 'checked' : '' }} class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radiobutton" id="create_post"
           value="create_post">
```

To:

```
<input {{ (old('radiobutton') && old('radiobutton') == 'create_post') ? 'checked' : '' }} class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radiobutton" id="create_post"
           value="create_post">
```

Comment: Thanks, but same issue, no radio button is checked after submit the form.

Comment: @AdamK did you check the value of `old('radiobutton')` ?

Comment: Do you know how to check that? Like this "{{old('radiobutton')}}" it seems that is empty.

Comment: {{var_dump(old('radiobutton')}}

Comment: It appears "NULL".